# Does A independent of B, and B correlated with C imply that C is independent of A?

Tags: covariance, expected-value, independence

Assume 3 random variables, $A, B, C$.

If $A \perp B$, but $Cov(B,C) \neq 0$, can we say anything about $Cov(A,C)$? I think it can either be 0 or not 0, but it seems like there should be more general results than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, certainly the covariance can be zero or nonzero:

Consider all three distributions discrete. Let $A$ be uniform on $\{-1,0,1\}$, $B$ uniform on $\{0,1\}$ and independent of $A$. Then

(i) if $C=A^2+B$ then $\text{Cov}(B,C)\neq 0$ but $\text{Cov}(A,C)= 0$

(ii) if $C=A+B$ then $\text{Cov}(B,C)\neq 0$ and $\text{Cov}(A,C)\neq 0$

But when you say "more general results" it's not at all clear to me what you want.